# Get the current path in Views

Tags: 7, views

What's the best way to get access to the current path in Views?

My use case is I want to use the current page path in a text area (i.e. I want to have a text field like More).

At the moment I'm handling it by using hook_views_re_view to rewrite a "Global: Custom Text" field value with drupal_get_path_alias().

Ideally I'd like something more portable, i.e. the ability to add a "Global: Current Path" field to my view.

What combination of hooks/handlers/plugins do I need to use?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot. I did go down the Views PHP route initially, but it struck me as a bit un-Drupally, and even Views PHP says to use handlers where possible.

In the end I used hook_views_data and did:

```
function mymodule_views_views_data() {
  $data['views']['current_path'] = array(
    'title' => t('Current Path'),
    'help' => t('Provide current path.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'concept2_views_handler_field_current_path',
    ),
  );
  return $data;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_handlers() to register all of the basic handlers
 * views uses.
 */
function mymodule_views_views_handlers() {
  return array(
    'info' => array(
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/handlers',
    ),
    'handlers' => array(
      // The name of my handler
      'mymodule_views_handler_field_current_path' => array(
        // The name of the handler we are extending.
        'parent' => 'views_handler_field',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

With a handler file like:

```
/**
 * A handler to provide a field that is completely custom by the administrator.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 */
class mymodule_views_handler_field_current_path extends views_handler_field {
  function query() {
    // do nothing -- to override the parent query.
  }

  function option_definition() {
    $options = parent::option_definition();

    // Override the alter text option to always alter the text.
    $options['alter']['contains']['alter_text'] = array('default' => TRUE, 'bool' => TRUE);
    $options['hide_alter_empty'] = array('default' => FALSE, 'bool' => TRUE);
    return $options;
  }

  function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
    parent::options_form($form, $form_state);
    unset($form['help']);
  }

  function render($values) {
    // Return the text, so the code never thinks the value is empty.
    return drupal_get_path_alias();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making a module or a patch for views for this so others can more easily make use of your efforts?

Comment: I was just about to code this but found this...it would be great even in a sandbox on d.o.

Comment: Great idea. I've taken this code, cleaned it up for Views 3.x and added it to a Drupal 7.x sandbox project. https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/hargobind/2331349

Comment: Correction, the sandbox is now a full project at https://www.drupal.org/project/views_current_path

Answer (score 2):

Use this module [views_current_path](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_current_path)

Comment: I created that module based on the code by @Apemantus above :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to do, you can choose one.

l() : print l(t('click here'), 'node/5');
This should print a link (a tag) with correct path of node/5. Aliased, and base paths are added automatically. Strongly recommended.

url(): print url('node/5'); 
This will print the correct path without an a tag. Base paths will be added. See api.drupal.org for its extra parameters.

request_uri(): this will give the current request uri.

base_path(): this will give base path of drupal site.

Answer (score -3):

Have you checked out [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php)? It has [some bugs](http://drupal.org/node/1140896) when accessing the $row variable but it works great for injecting PHP into a Views field.

You could use [request_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7#comment-40028) in a Views PHP field:

```
Whatever text you want plus a <a href="<?php print request_path(); ?>">link</a> to the current page.
```

Comment: No need to hardcode a tags when l() can do it.